# Error while restarting MS Outlook, but "sleep 30" fixes error

Tags: vba, powershell, outlook, com

Script body:

```
$Outlook = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application")
$Outlook.quit()
Get-Process OUTLOOK -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Wait-Process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE"
#sleep 30
$Outlook = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application")
$NameSpace = $Outlook.getNamespace("MAPI")
$NameSpace.stores | where {$_.ExchangeStoreType -eq 3} | Select-Object DisplayName,FilePath
```

I'd like to restart MS Outlook and get a list of PST files. The code doesn't work with an error:

```
Exception calling "GetActiveObject" with "1" argument(s): "Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))"
At C:\open1\restart-outlook.ps1:6 char:1
+ $Outlook = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("Outloo ...
```

If I uncomment "sleep 30" in line 5 the code will work. But computers are different some need "sleep 120" to get MS Outlook fully operational. Is there any other way besides putting "sleep" operator in the code?

Comment: Just use a Do...Until/While loop to wait until Outlook responds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use the [Marshal.GetActiveObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getactiveobject?view=netframework-4.8) method to get the running instance of Outlook twice. Typically, it is used when you want to get the already running instance, not started by your code. But even if you create a new `Application` instance for automating it you get the same results because Outlook is a singleton - you can't start two instances simultaneously.

Instead of using the sleep statement in the code I'd suggest handling the [MAPILogonComplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.mapilogoncomplete) event of the Application class which is fired after the user has logged onto the system. So, in the event handler you may get all the required information.

Comment: Thanks. If somebody could give me an example of how to "Wait-Event Application_MAPILogonComplete" that would be helpful

Comment: I'd suggest posting a new question there, so users could recognize questions and answers easily.